Avtomation обход капчи cloudflare turnstile (JS)
Нужно помочь обойти капчу на проекте  Cloudflare turnstile captcha . Стек Js Playwright. Нет whitelist поэтому не получается просто добавить ip в список или прокинуть заголовок. Нужно придумать решение.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
